# Spring boot security in kotlin with users and roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I have to work on an application that old interns started. The backend is made with spring-boot and using Kotlin, which I'm very new to both. The backed is a RESTful API and I need to implement an authentication and authorizations to limit the access to specific users the CRUD methods.

There's basically two user roles I need to create, an admin and a moderator one that can have access to less methods.

Does anyone have a guide on to how to make it possible?

I've found [this](https://bezkoder.com/spring-boot-jwt-authentication/) tutorial which seems like to do what I'm looking for but it's in java and I'm not able to code everything back into Kotlin.

Also, add access restriction on a websocket as well?

Comment: This question is very abstract, but as long you know the requrements and know how to set this up in Java, I'll suggest that you start with Java and run convert to Kotlin using e.g. IntelliJ. The Kotlin code will be very similar. BR

Comment: Thanks I tried it and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is official guide for configuring security on Kotlin:
https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/04/spring-tips-kotlin-and-spring-security

Security for websockets has two parts for configuring:

- for controllers
- for message brokers

There is guide for that https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-websockets on Java, but following the example in security configuration on Kotlin you will be able to convert Java to Kotlin, anyway you can always convert Java classes in Kotlin classes in your `Intellij Idea` as on image:[image]